# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bookingformtools'

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, django-formtools

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    'booking'

    'crispy_forms',
    'formtools',
]
```

the error,
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bookingformtools'`

Pip installed django-crispy-forms and django-formtools. Added them to settings.py and the project won't run. Tried using both a virtual environment and otherwise. Not quite sure why I am getting a module error. Pip show is not helping either.

Comment: You have comma missing after `booking`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM :)